# Executing sqoop statements from shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, sqoop

i have an input file like below. having table name in column 1 and remaining portion left in that line is sqoop statement ending with ;. i have to loop the tables and run each sqoop statements. i am able to read tables but as sqoop statement is having spaces i am unable to read whole statement as coulmn2. can anyone help with this.

```
input file
tbl1|sqoop import --options file /location --table tbl1 --target-dir /location --hiveimport ;
tbl2|sqoop import --options file /location --table tbl2 --target-dir /location --hiveimport --compression;
tbl3|sqoop import --options file /location --table tbl3 --target-dir /location --hiveimport --compression;
```

Now i am able to read input file first column but i am not getting how to read whole sqoop statement as one .below is what i have tried but didn't worked.

```
while read line; do
tbl_name=$(echo "$line"|awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print $1}'}
echo "tbl name is $tbl_name" >> "$tbl_name".log
tablestring=${line#"$tbl_name")
for sqoop_statement in ${tablestring//;/ }; do
echo "$sqoop_statement" >> "$tbl_name".log
echo "sqoop statement executed successfully for  $tbl_name" >> "$tbl_name".log
done
done < input.txt
```

NOTE : Input file is self created to can be modified and each line in input file is having table name then pipe delimeter then sqoop import statement terminating with ;

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you're doing in a single line of awk.

```sh
awk -F"|" '{print "running the command for "$1"\n"$2" >> "$1".log"; st=system($2">>"$1".log");print (st==0?"Success\n":"Failure\n")}' input.txt
```

#### Expanded version

```
{
    print "running the command for " $1 "\n" $2 " >> " $1 ".log"
    st = system($2 ">>" $1 ".log")
    print (st == 0 ? "Success\n" : "Failure\n")
}
```